# selecting from drop down list using selenium3.0.2 and python3.5.1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, firefoxdriver

This is my first question in OS and I would describe it in details with my best effort.

Selenium3.0.2

firefox 45.6.0

geckodriver 0.13.0

python 3.5.1 (with Anaconda 2.4.1 (64bit))

What I want to do is to automate the process of registering a new facebook account. The below code can set values in boxes such as "first name" and "password".

However, it cannot make any selection from the drop down list, such "day", "month", or "year"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

from datetime import datetime
import unittest, time, re

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
browser.maximize_window()

browser.find_element_by_id("u_0_1").send_keys("firstName")
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("u_0_3").send_keys("lastName")
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("u_0_5").send_keys("testSelenium@email.com")
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("u_0_8").send_keys("testSelenium@email.com")
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("u_0_a").send_keys("testpassword")
time.sleep(2)

Select(browser.find_element_by_id("month")).select_by_visible_text("Jan")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("month")).select_by_visible_text("Feb")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("month")).select_by_visible_text("Apr")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("month")).select_by_visible_text("Dec")
time.sleep(2)

Select(browser.find_element_by_id("day")).select_by_visible_text("1")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("day")).select_by_visible_text("7")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("day")).select_by_visible_text("11")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("day")).select_by_visible_text("28")
time.sleep(2)

Select(browser.find_element_by_id("year")).select_by_visible_text("1990")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("year")).select_by_visible_text("1991")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("year")).select_by_visible_text("1992")
time.sleep(2)
Select(browser.find_element_by_id("year")).select_by_visible_text("1993")
time.sleep(2)

#select gender
browser.find_element_by_id("u_0_i").click()
```

Comment: Try seperating this line of code into two, Select(browser.find_element_by_id("month")).select_by_visible_text("Jan"); first click on the month button, wait for half a second then click on an item on its dropdown list.

Comment: @YuZhang Thanks! I tried this but still not working. Turns out using selenium2 works well on this.

Comment: all good, glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

The above code works well with the following setup:

Python3.5.2 (anaconda3 4.2.0)

Firefox 45.6.0

selenium 2.53.1

I think either selenium3 or the gechodriver has bug on this.